# Machine learning for multi-level response

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, many-categories

I have a dataset with ~90000 observations and less than 10 features (all continuous). The problem is that the response variable has ~300 categories. Currently I would try to fit a multinomial linear model or a random forest. I have to predict probabilities for the 300 categories. I need some inspiration and would like to know which model others would use?

Comment: I would think that a random forest would handle this well.  Are you sure that your RF settings are appropriately set?

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you are interested in probabilities (and not just prediction) this will impact your choice of algorithm. You really have to choices:

1. Use a classifier that predicts well-calibrated probabilities.
2. Use any multiclass classifier and attempt to calibrate the probabilities using something like Platt scaling or isotonic regression, see section 2.2 of the paper
   [Calibrating Random Forest](http://people.dsv.su.se/~henke/papers/bostrom08b.pdf) for a brief description of the techniques and related references.

I would probably start with the first option using [Multinomial Logistic Regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) and then maybe a Neural Network if I felt I was underfitting. As someone said in a comment, random forests seem like a good option, but you'll likely need to calibrate them somehow (using the technique in the first paper I linked?). Another good reference for getting probabilities out of supervised classifiers is the aptly titled [Predicting Good Probabilities With Supervised Learning](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2005_Niculescu-MizilC05.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with many class problems like this, some of the classes will likely be not well represented.  If you are really interested in getting these "not-well-represented" classes right, aka increasing the number of True Positives but generating a lot of False Positives, you may need to tune your model.  In Random Forest you will need to play with [class weights or sampling strategies](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/666.pdf) that up sample the not well represented classes.

[K-Nearest-Neighbors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) is another potential classifier.